# Delete values of row when import csv

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, csv

I have import csv file method with carrierwave and it's works. And now I want to delete values of row when that have been successful imported to database.

```
csv_text = File.read(file_csv.current_path)
csv = CSV.parse(csv_text)
csv.each_with_index do |row, index|
  @foo = Foo.new(bar: row[0])
  if @foo.save
    # delete values of row
  else
    next
  end
end
```

Example I have a file csv containing :

```
lenovo z360, black, 14
asus a46, blue, nil
MacBook Pro, silver
```

lenovo z360 and MacBook Pro has been successful import, and the end of process import file will be like this :

```
asus a46, blue, nil
```

Is it possible ? How would I be able just to read, write/delete and manipule a file with many of row?

Comment: you can try writing the unprocessed rows in a new file.  Then after that, use `FileUtils.mv` to move the newly written file to the old file.

Comment: @jvnill mmphh, ok I think I need push to an array value of row can't import, and after finish import, I need open new file csv and each an array to write it and save.